# Error while sending a plot to html in flask

Tags: python, html, plot, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using flask web server and want to do the following functionality.

- Pass form data from home.html to python func plot_perf_metric().
- Save form data and call plot.html.
- plot.html calls output_plot() which generates a plot based on the saved form data and accessing values from a database(mongodb).
- plot.html prints this plot.

I am currently not getting the image displayed.

I only get a broken link of the image.

Can someone help me?

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form action="./plot" method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="perf_metric" value="disk"> Disk <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="perf_metric" value="memory"> Memory <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="perf_metric" value="cpu"> CPU <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="perf_metric" value="egress"> Egress <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="perf_metric" value="flit"> Flit <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_plot" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
from flask import request,make_response
from pymongo import MongoClient
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import StringIO
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
     return render_template('home.html')


def connect_mongo(text):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client['mydb']
    collection = db['vload']
    b = list()
    a = list(collection.find())
    for i in range(len(a)):
        b.append(a[i][text])
        return b

@app.route('/output')
def output_plot():
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    b=connect_mongo(plot_perf_metric.text)
    fig = axis.plot(b)
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    response = make_response(output.getvaluest())
    response.mimetype = 'image/png'
    fig.savefig(output)
    output.seek(0)
    return send_file(output, mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/plot',methods=['POST'])
def plot_perf_metric():

if(request.form['submit_plot'] == "Send"):
    text = request.form['perf_metric']
    return render_template('plot.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

plot.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Plot</title>
</head>
<body>
     <img src="{{ url_for('output_plot') }}" alt="Image Placeholder" height="100">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will you please give full taceback ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a route for `output_plot`.

```
@app.route('/output')
def output_plot():
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    b=connect_mongo(plot_perf_metric.text)
    fig = axis.plot(b)
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    response = make_response(output.getvaluest())
    response.mimetype = 'image/png'
    fig.savefig(output)
    output.seek(0)
    return send_file(output, mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: After adding the route, I am getting a broken image, not the plot that I want

Comment: You probably have an error in your logs. My guess is it's an `AttributeError` on `plot_perf_metric.text`. You can't access a variable inside a function like that.

Comment: Yes your right. I found it in online that you can access a variable in a function like that outside of that function. Is there any other way to do it other than using global variables?

Comment: You could write a function that returns the value. You can then call the function wherever you need the value.